# MYSQL Procedure for inserting data in to table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Very new to mysql, want to write a PROCEDURE, which will insert data into my table but getting syntax error,

query to fetch the last id value,

```
select max(id) from activity where x_id='1242614'
```

I want to start the insert next to the `max(id)` value,

I have designed this below but getting syntax error,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERTDATA(P1 INT)
BEGIN
    SET @X = 0;
        REPEAT 
            SET @X = @X + 1;
            UNTIL @X > P1
    END REPEAT;
    END
```

[image]

Comment: Please add full text of the error message (using [edit])

Comment: But, reading your question, I think you can better use [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: In the error message (the TEXT, not PICTURE) that is cut-off of the picture, there is a text that starts with "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ......".  The error is just before the text that is mentioned on the ........

Comment: It looks like your client thinks you are executing multiple statements. You probably need to set a custom `DELIMITER` but the method of doing that varies depending on which MySQL client you use.